# Compress very large Integers into smallest possible string

Tags: c#, compression

I want to Compress Integers (~20 digits) to smaller strings with symbols.
I succeeded, but it only works for Integers under about 16 digits.

I guess it's some kind of rounding Mistake. Does anyone know how to fix it, or another way to compress Integers to String with custom Characters?
Thank you in advance!

Example:

does work in both ways:
822152842686533 => 6OKYXLtml
6OKYXLtml => 822152842686533

does not work in both ways:
25478562549632547 => 3OxGclFmZ9
3OxGclFmZ9 => 25478562549632553

```
private List<char> symbollist = new List<char> { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

private string Compress(decimal code)
    {
        if (code < 1)
            return "0";

        string codestring = "";

        List<char> charlist = new List<char>();
        while (code > 1)
        {
            charlist.Add(symbollist[(int)(code % symbollist.Count)]);
            code /= symbollist.Count;
        }
        for (int i = charlist.Count-1; i >=0; i--)
        {
            codestring += charlist[i];
        }
        return codestring;
    }
private decimal DeCompress(string code)
    {
        decimal codedec = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
        {
            codedec += symbollist.IndexOf(code[i]) * (decimal)System.Math.Pow(symbollist.Count, code.Length - 1 - i);
        }
        return codedec;
    }
```

Comment: Does it have to be human readable?  Why are you choosing a string?  An int is already 4 bytes, it cannot get any smaller. You could encode the 4 bytes as a latin-1 string but you're not going to save any space. In fact the string will be longer.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qrm2o4

Comment: Base64 encodes binary data into printable strings pretty efficiently. If you have, for example, a 64-bit number (0 to +/-  9*10^18), that can be encoded into 11 base64 digits (I think my math is right). However, as @rowan points out, an 11 character string (encoded as UTF-8) will require 88 bits, not 64.

Comment: Odd that you leave out v and w from the alphabets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `System.Math.Pow` is using `double`, not `decimal`, and does not have enough precision for your larger number. A `double` has only 52 bits of mantissa, whereas your second example is a 55-bit integer.

You don't need a power function anyway, and you don't need to reverse the digits when encoding. Encode with the least significant digits first, in the order you generate them. Then when decoding, maintain a base to the nth power by multiplying by the base each time. Use that to multiply each digit when adding. Do all the multiplications and additions with `decimal` arithmetic, to retain the needed precision.

Something like:

```
private List<char> symbollist = new List<char> { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

private string Compress(decimal code)
    {
        string codestring = "";
        do
        {
            codestring += symbollist[(int)(code % symbollist.Count)];
            code = Decimal.Floor(code / symbollist.Count);
        } while (code >= 1);
        return codestring;
    }
private decimal DeCompress(string code)
    {
        if (code.Length == 0)
            return 0;
        decimal codedec = symbollist.IndexOf(code[0]);
        decimal pos = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < code.Length; i++)
        {
            pos *= symbollist.Count;
            codedec += symbollist.IndexOf(code[i]) * pos;
        }
        return codedec;
    }
```

Example input, coded, decoded (using all of the mantissa bits of a `decimal` type):

```
79228162514264337593543950335
b8NYXtnuNafbQGBo4
79228162514264337593543950335
```

(Note: your code should do something about the presence of fractions. Either remove the fraction before encoding, or return an error. Also handle invalid digits.)